# How does the most effective circuit control multiple contacts with a rotary switch?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, switches, relay, control

I will create an electrical circuit to turn on the LCD in 2 ways, namely through the microcontroller and through the header pin. If I rotate the rotary switch to the left then all LCD pins are connected with the header pin, and if I rotate the rotary switch to the right then all LCD pins will be connected to the microcontroller. Help me find the electrical circuit.

[image: here's the schematic]

Answer (score 0):

Seems you require a "4 Pole 3 Position Rotary Switch", similar to [this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/123704779015?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=123704779015&targetid=1262779892049&device=c&mktype=&googleloc=9003591&poi=&campaignid=14859008593&mkgroupid=130497710760&rlsatarget=pla-1262779892049&abcId=9300678&merchantid=8433394&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgImM0fGI9wIV6AaICR32FApuEAQYAyABEgL-lvD_BwE).  Not the most common but they are available. Schematically the rotary switch can be shown as below:
[image]
Your 4 LCD pins would connect at the common inputs of A, B, C, and D.
Your 4 Micro-controller signals could then connect to A1, B1, C1, and D1.
Connections A2, B2, C2, and D2 would be unconnected.
Your header pin signals would connect at A3, B3, C3 and D3.

Note that since this is a serial driven LCD quickly changing the signals from one switch end to the other while the system is powered may cause the LCD to freeze up or show an odd display, though it may update after a short time. Ideally it would be best to adjust the rotary switch with the system in the powered off state.

It may also be helpful to place a pull-up or pull-down resistor on the LCD's SDA and SCL lines, this way during switching the control signals are not left floating with potentially uncontrolled noise on them. (The pull-up or pull-down type depends on the LCD's signal requirements.)

.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, besides that I will also make the same circuit on a dc motor that has 6 pins and a keypad that has 8 pins, which I know there is no rotary switch that has 6 or 8 poles and 3 positions. is there another alternative solution?

Comment: You could likely find almost any configuration you need. Though you might pay a lot for the less common types. One better idea (if you really want a rotary switch option) is to use a type that is configurable with positions and poles. If you look very closely at some types you can see that they are assembled in layers using long screws and end nuts. You would just need to adjust the positions, (with a pin or tab), then add the needed number of pole layers. You could also do a search for 6P3T rotary switch, you'll get several hits. There are likely other options but use a new question inquiry.

Comment: It's sounds good, your answer is very helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it was helpful to you. If the answer was acceptable you can also click on the Accept check mark at the top left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a single-pole, multi-position switch, then you can control multi-contact relays. Each switch position actuates one relay. The multiple relay contacts are wired to give the output logic you need.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid sending the LCD signals through a rotary switch and risk problems as Nedd implies, how about using a couple of analog switch chips to select which source of the 4 signals are connected to the LCD?  This would then allow one control signal to route all lines, and just a toggle switch to select the source.

Something like this quad analog switch chip, one for the micro signals, and one for the header:
[image: M74HC4316B quad analog switch]
When the pin 15 "1C" control signal is high, pins 1 and 2 are connected together.  The same goes for 2C, 3C, etc.

To switch your signals, connect all the "C" lines of each chip together and drive one set high and the other low with your select switch or toggle switch which now doesn't need 4 poles.  Set the control lines high for the micro data switch while the header's lines switch control is low and vice-versa.

https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/47/e7/2d/a9/66/57/41/30/CD00000326.pdf/files/CD00000326.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000326.pdf